# Silverlight - Hardcoding private key

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

If I hardcode a private key in a Windows Phone application, can people extract it once the application is released to the public on the Windows Store?

I am asking this because I have found no way of accessing installed certificates from the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I don't know the specific details of what you're trying to do, but I will say that putting sensitive information like passwords or private keys and the like into your application is almost always a bad idea. As fantastically productive .net is, it's also extremely easy to reverse engineer (in fact many, many advanced developers reverse programs just to improve their own skills). A cryptographic schema is typically only as strong as the key is secure. If someone were to determine the key on one phone, it sounds like they would have access to the key on *all phones*, which is kind of a problem.

It would be better to store this information remotely and have the user authenticate before they can access their private key (or whatever other secure information you're trying to store).

Comment: @sirecodesalot Thank you for your response.  I have a web service which I want to be used by my mobile applications only.  How can I do that?  First, I thought of using certificates, however I found out that Silverlight does not support sending certificates.  Then I thought of storing the private key of the certificate in the application, however your answer suggests that this is not a good idea.  What can I do to identify that the application calling the web service is my mobile application?

Comment: Hmm. Are you saying that it matters whether a user is contacting your service from a mobile as opposed to say a computer or tablet? I mean if that's the case you would just transmit that information when the user signs into the service. That's perfectly "safe" information to encode into your application in that it's not particularly sensitive. Although if you're using Silverlight, it sounds a whole lot like this is a web based application than a windows-phone app. If you're hosting your Silverlight application in a web-page you should be able to determine the browser/device used.