# Storing private data at Windows Phone

Tags: encryption, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce, windows-phone

I'm developing app for storing some private user data. I use sql-server-ce database. Data can contain images. In future, app will be able to synchronize with SkyDrive. So I have a few questions about data encryption:

1. What is the best way to encrypt data? Encrypt all databse (with `Password` option), or just data (with AES128, as in database)?
2. Where to store assymetric key (for AES). Can I store it as constant in code (I guess no: [Silverlight - Hardcoding private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280302/silverlight-hardcoding-private-key)), or should I use `ProtectedData` class? As I understand, `ProtectedData` items are linked to current device, so I won't be able to synchronize that generated key to another device?
3. How to store images? As separated encrypted files, or as Blob column in database? For all app it can be about 50 full-res images. I would like to store them at database, but will it impact performance (e.g. I want to show all 50 thumbs that stores at another Blob column, but with LINQ I select all rows, so they will be all loaded to memory?).

Comment: This is not enough to get it over to SkyDrive, but it has some good info on how to store data secure on Windows Phone: http://robtiffany.com/encrypting-your-credentials-on-windows-phone-7-5/

Comment: Yep, I saw that article. It's about `ProtectedData`. I guess, I need kind of transport password temporarily encrypt AES key (cause I can't use `ProtectedData` for that)